# How to use a generated file by script in Bamboo as artifact

Tags: bamboo, bamboo-artifacts

I create a Python file to generate a json file with Bamboo script job. Now I need to upload the generated file to S3. How can I make it as artifact, from that I can reuse it in the next jobs?

Answer (score 0):

To make Bamboo identify a json file as artifact, all you need to do is to define an artifact definition as described in the [official documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamkb/bamboo-artifact-definition-syntax-examples-815581285.html). This way, you can make Bamboo recognise the json file produced from the script task(/job?).

Then, make the artifact shareable as described on this page - [Sharing artifacts](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/sharing-artifacts-359400060.html) so that next jobs can use them.